# Example of a nonzero ideal which is contained in every other non zero ideal.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, primary-decomposition

I am searching for a ring in which $0$ ideal is irreducible but not primary. I have an idea to show that $0$ ideal is irreducible : We have to construct a ring $R$ in such a way that there exist a nontrivial ideal $J$ such that $J \subseteq I$ for every non trivial ideal $I$ of $R.$ In this case, clearly, $0$ ideal is irreducible. Since, in noetherian rings, irreducible ideals are primary, we have to get examples in a non noetherian rings.

> So I want an example of a non noetherian commutative ring with unity which has a nonzero ideal which is contained in every other ideal.

Comment: Can you construct a ring with only two proper ideals?

Comment: This will sadly be a non-commutative example, but if we look at the ring of bounded operators over a Hilbert space $H$ then the ideal of finite-rank operators on $H$ must be contained in any other non-zero ideal (I don't know if that can be extended to generic Banach spaces).

Comment: @SergeyGuminov How does it help?  That would be a Noetherian ring, still.

Comment: @rschwieb The comment was written before OP edited the question.

Comment: @Mark Granted. At the time I wrote they both said "1 hour ago" and I did not know the timestamps had detailed mouseovers until now.  That much is on me. But still it suggests a route that has no hope of working, given a standard result on Noetherian rings, so some comment has to be made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I want an example of a non noetherian commutative ring with unity which has a nonzero ideal which is contained in every other ideal.*

The following are commutative non-Noetherian rings with simple, essential socles.  This amounts to the intersection of nonzero ideals being nonzero.

1. $ \mathbb F_2[x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots ]/(\{x_i^3\mid i\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{x_ix_j\mid i\neq j\}\cup\{x_i^2-x_j^2\mid i,j\in \mathbb N\}),$ where $\mathbb F_2$ is the field of two elements.
2. The trivial extension $D(+)V$ where $D=F[[x]]$ for a field $F$, and $V=F((x))/D$
3. The trivial extension $\mathbb Z (+) \mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$ of a Prüfer $p$-group by the integers.
4. The monoid ring $\mathbb F_2[M]$ where $\mathbb F_2$ is the field of two elements and $M$ is the monoid structure on the interval $[0,1]$ where

$$ab:=
\begin{cases}
a+b & \text{ if } a+b \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}.
$$

The ideals of the second and fourth one are actually linearly ordered.  The first and fourth one are not useful to you because they are local with nil radical, so $\{0\}$ is primary.

To see $\{0\}$ is not primary in the third one, take an element of the Prüfer group of order $p$, say $x$, then $(0,x)(p,0)=0$, and yet $(0,x)$ is not zero, and $(p,0)$ is not nilpotent.

The second one will also work for you, for similar reasons. You can use $a=(0, x^{-1}+k[[x]])$ as a nonzero element, and $b=(x,0)$ as a non-nilpotent element, and $ab=0$.

Clearly you can see the trivial extension construction is useful for creating non-primary zero ideals!

---

I'm using $(+)$ to denote the trivial extension. In detail, if we have a ring $R$ and a module $M$, the underlying set of $R(+)M$ is $R\times M$ and the operations are coordinatewise addition, and multiplication that is $(a,m)(b,n):=(ab,an+mb)$. Writing it as $R(+)M$ is just a way to make sure it's not confused for the product ring.

Comment: [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=98l&H=101l&L=64l)

Comment: What is the meaning of $(+)$ in 2 and 3 ?

Comment: @3f183201 Is this explanation ok?

Comment: Looks okay, but need some time to work out details

Comment: @3f183201 LMK if I can help!

Comment: @3f183201 This morning I actually sat down and checked the other three for suitability to your original question. Looks like two work two don't!

Comment: In example 1, what is $m$? (in the expression $x_i^2 - m$)

Comment: @math54321 Ah, good question.  It's actually better expressed in the original paper `V. Camillo, W. Nicholson, and M. Yousif. Ikeda--Nakayama rings.` The idea is to get $x_i^2=x_j^2$ for all $i,j$ (I changed it to this now.) in the end, they express the simple socle as $F_2m$ where $m$ is that common value the $x_i^2$ are all equal to.

Comment: Yes, this clearly is the intended way to make the socle simple, thanks!